# How to characterize abrupt change?

Tags: time-series, trend, change-point

This question may be too basic. For a temporal trend of a data, I would like to find out the point where "abrupt" change happens. For example, in the first figure shown below, I would like to find out the change point using some statistic method. And I would like to apply such method in some other data of which the change point is not obvious (like the 2nd figure).So is there a common method for such purpose?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the term "turning point" has a particular meaning that I don't think applies to a sudden shift in level (whether up or down). You also use the phrase 'change point', and I think that's probably a better choice. Please don't think this is 'too basic'; even basic questions are welcome with no need for apology, and this question isn't remotely basic.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the 'turning point' to 'change point' in the question.

Answer (score 12):

If the observations of your time series data are correlated with the immediately previous observations, the paper by [Chen and Liu (1993)](http://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321)$^{[1]}$ may interest you. It describes a method to detect level shifts and temporary changes in the framework of autoregressive moving-average time series models.

[1]: Chen, C. and Liu, L-M. (1993),
"Joint Estimation of Model Parameters and Outlier Effects in Time Series,"
*Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **88**:421, 284-297

Comment: +1 I was trying (but failing) to remember enough about this paper to locate it. It's a good reference.

Answer (score 10):

This problem in Stats is referred to as the (univariate) Temporal Event Detection. The simplest idea is to use a moving average and standard deviation. Any reading that is "out of" 3-standard deviations (rule-of-thumb) is considered an "event". There of course, are more advanced models that use HMMs, or Regression. Here is an introductory [overview of the field](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~neill/papers/eventdetection.pdf).

Comment: This is the *only* post publicly accessible on the entire Web to include the phrase "Univariate Temporal Event Detection"! What is your source for this term?

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. Event Detection is a more common term, and Temporal is sometimes used separately. Univariate is not commonly used as the approaches are typically multivariate, but it is his special case.

Comment: edited the answer to incorporate your comment @whuber

Comment: @ser1669710 Thanks. This is what I am looking for. Seems that moving average cannot solve my problem. I need to look at the more complicated model.

Comment: I would like to learn more about this temporal event detection. The slides you posted are nice, but I was wondering if you have the link to a review paper that describes the field a bit more formally?

Comment: Just to note that, as an expert in this field, whilst this may be practically useful the moving average window and 3sd rule of thumb works extremely poorly for many problems in practice. Many of the other answers give solutions that are theoretical founded and shown to give correct results.

Answer (score 5):

This inference problem has many names, including change points, switch points, break points, broken line regression, broken stick regression, bilinear regression, piecewise linear regression, local linear regression, segmented regression, and discontinuity models.

[Here is an overview of change point packages](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html) with pros/cons and worked examples. If you know the number of change points a priori, check out the `mcp` package. First, let's simulate the data:

```r
df = data.frame(x = seq(1, 12, by = 0.1))
df$y = c(rnorm(21, 0, 5), rnorm(80, 180, 5), rnorm(10, 20, 5))
```

For your first problem, it's three intercept-only segments:

```r
model = list(
  y ~ 1,  # Intercept
  ~ 1,  # etc...
  ~ 1
)
library(mcp)
fit = mcp(model, df, par_x = "x")
```

We can plot the resulting fit:

```r
plot(fit)
```

[image]

Here, the change points are very well defined (narrow). Let's summarise the fit to see their inferred locations (`cp_1` and `cp_2`):

```r
summary(fit)

Family: gaussian(link = 'identity')
Iterations: 9000 from 3 chains.
Segments:
  1: y ~ 1
  2: y ~ 1 ~ 1
  3: y ~ 1 ~ 1

Population-level parameters:
    name   mean lower upper Rhat n.eff
    cp_1   3.05   3.0   3.1    1  6445
    cp_2  11.05  11.0  11.1    1  6401
   int_1   0.14  -1.9   2.1    1  5979
   int_2 179.86 178.8 180.9    1  6659
   int_3  22.76  19.8  25.5    1  5906
 sigma_1   4.68   4.1   5.3    1  5282
```

You can do much more complicated models with `mcp`, including modeling Nth-order autoregression (useful for time series), etc. Disclosure: I am the developer of `mcp`.

Answer (score 4):

The area of statistics that you are looking for is changepoint analysis.  There is a website [here](http://www.changepoint.info) that will give you an overview of the area and also have a page for software.

If you are an `R` user then i'd recommend the `changepoint` package for changes in mean and the `strucchange` package for changes in regression.  If you want to be Bayesian then the `bcp` package is good too.

In general you have to choose a threshold which indicates the strength of the changes you are looking for.  There are, of course, threshold choices that people advocate in certain situations and you can use asymptotic confidence levels or bootstrapping to get confidence too.

Comment: The OP identified two examples, one of which I would call a step and the other a ramp, although there is always scope for wrangling about words. See also my answer here. How do these methods cope with ramps? Do they have a tacit or explicit model of stepped change?

Comment: Thanks for the question Nick.  Generally it depends on how long the ramp is.  If it is a short ramp then it is treated as 1 change, if the ramp is longer then often the changepoint methods will identify 2 changes, 1 at the start of the ramp and 1 at the end.  Obviously this does depend on the underlying model that you assume.

Answer (score 2):

Try [roerich library](https://github.com/HSE-LAMBDA/roerich) for abrupt change detection in time series. It contains several algorithms for change point detection. Each of them returns a score that you can use to characterize the detected changes.

Example on a simple case with several abrupt changes:

```
import numpy as np
# generate a sample
n = 100
X1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(n, 1))
X2 = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, size=(n, 1))
X3 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(n, 1))
X = np.concatenate((X1, X2, X3), axis=0)
cps_true = [n, 2*n]
```

Now, apply one of the algorithms in the library:

```
import roerich
from roerich.change_point import SlidingWindows

# change points detection
cpd = SlidingWindows(window_size=20, metric='energy', bootstrap=False, n_runs=1)
score, cps_pred = cpd.predict(X)

# visualization
roerich.display(X, cps_true, score, cps_pred=None)
```

Result:

[image]

More examples are in this short [intro](https://medium.com/@hushchyn.mikhail/change-point-detection-using-roerich-13d85ec14d60) on Medium.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Thank you for your answer, but please do disclose any involvement you have with software libraries you recommend. That could be as simple as changing "Try [roerich library](https://github.com/HSE-LAMBDA/roerich)" to "Try my [roerich library](https://github.com/HSE-LAMBDA/roerich)". See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) for guidance.

Comment: Please note that the sliding window approach proposed here is heavily dependent on the window size chosen for detection properties. There are approaches that use a selection of window sizes to ensure better detection properties, I suggest the work of Claudia Kirch and coauthors in developing MOSUM for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and easy way to do it. Create a bunch of jump functions like this:
$$
J_i = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l}
       0 & x < x_i\\ 1 & x \ge x_i
      \end{array}\right.
$$
for candidate cutoff points $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_m$. Now use stepwise regression to select the best model with the $J_i$ as possible predictors. In your first example, assuming you select two predictors, you'll get one for $J_{april}$ with a positive coefficient equal to the size of the jump upward, and one for $J_{december}$ with a negative coefficient equal to the size of the jump downward. You need to decide how finely you want to divide the candidate jump times, $x_i$, e.g., one per month, one per fortnight, one per week, one per day.

There are more elegant and exacting solutions involving nonlinear regression, where you use a model with $J_1$ and $J_2$ and estimate $x_1$ and $x_2$ as parameters. It's a bit messy to set up.

Comment: PS - @user1669710 and I posted answers simultaneously. I voted for that one because it is obviously better researched. But I'm leaving this here as it is an alternative that does work and is easy to implement.

Comment: Because it uses stepwise regression and employs many candidate variables, this procedure looks suspect. Where has it been studied and what properties does it have?  How does it compare to other [tag:changepoint] methods?

Comment: @whuber, my point exactly. That's why I voted for the other answer. It won't compare too favorably if you have a very granular set of changepoint values. And it might not even compare that favorably otherwise. I'm just putting it out as an *ad hoc* method, and I think I presented it as such. But I think a method like this promises to be a good way to obtain starting values for the nonlinear method.

Comment: The *idea* underlies some of the more effective changepoint methods I have found, but the use of stepwise regression in particular makes me suspect (although I am unsure) that this method could fail even to produce reasonable starting points for other methods to improve on. That is why I am curious whether it has even been studied.

Comment: I think there would few problems with all-subsets selection, as long as there really are a specified number of jumps (say two), as we'd find the two jumps that best explain the data. Other selection methods could be problematic, just as they are in other situations. I think it depends on how important it is to get the best answer, versus a good answer, versus a quick answer. Not all problems are the same, nor are all clients. The best answer in the world is an utter failure if you can't explain it.

Comment: My concerns are (1) entire groups of these indicators might be selected instead of just one per jump, especially when the jump occurs over the course of more than one time step (which might not be a big deal, but some post-processing would be required); (2) whether all-subsets selection would ever run to completion even with a modest time series like the one in the second graphic, which appears to have hundreds of steps; (3) whether in cases like that one the algorithm might not find a very large number of "significant" jumps; and (4) whether it might lack power to detect gradual changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related problem of dividing a series or sequence into spells with ideally constant values. See [How can I group numerical data into naturally forming "brackets"? (e.g. income)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67571/how-can-i-group-numerical-data-into-naturally-forming-brackets-e-g-income)

It's not quite the same problem as the question doesn't exclude spells with slow drift in any or all directions, but without abrupt changes.

A more direct answer is to say that we are looking for big jumps, so the only real issue is to define jump. The first idea is then just to look at first differences between neighbouring values. It's not even clear that you need to refine that by removing noise first, as if jumps can't be distinguished from differences in noise, they surely can't be abrupt. On the other hand, the questioner evidently wants abrupt change to include ramped as well as stepped change, so some criterion such as variance or range within fixed-length windows seems called for.